# String contains reserved builtin global variable name issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Given:**

```
text = "text#$!text" #Note: #$! is normal string not a variable
```

returns: `"texttext"`

And

```
text = 'text#$!text' # with single quote
```

returns: `"text\#$!text"`

**Question:**

How can I just get `"text#$!text"` as result because it is required to be hardcoded and used as password, so it can't contain backslashes `\`

Comment: The backslash is just for display purposes and is not actually part of the `String`. e.g. `'text#$!text'.include?("\\") #=> false`

Comment: What do you mean by "returns"? There are no method definitions nor method calls in your code, so who is returning what from where to where?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I should've used 'prints' instead of 'returns' coz I am checking it in console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslash is part of how the string is represented by `inspect`, like the quotes; neither are part of the actual string itself.

Note that `text[0, 5]`, for example, is `"text#"`.